# React Native - Android - Duplicate Class Found

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo

I have come across a really strange problem here. The react native app works perfectly on iOS but not on Android. Every time I try to build for Andorid I get the error:

```
Duplicate class found
```

I've searched everywhere online but can't find a solution.

When I click on the "Duplicate class found" warning I get hundreds of messages like this:

```
Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.x509.util.StreamParsingException found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15on-1.65 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.65) and jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.69 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.69)
```

I'm all out of ideas so any help is welcome!

```
Android Studio version: Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1

classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
```

Comment: I found a solution to this by removing Stripe as it was causing the issue. I will update when I get a full answer! hope this helps someone!